# Excel file too large - 340 mb - Migrate to access?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an excel file about 340 mb which contains more than 2000 worksheets and dozens of long VBA program. The file is getting so large that it takes around 10-15 mins to open the file and often get into "NO RESPONSE", "NOT ENOUGH USEABLE RESOURCES" when I save or debug the file.

I searched online people suggest migrating to Acesss. However, I have never used Access before. SO I wonder

1) How to migrate the excel file to access? 
2) Will the VBA program be carried to the new access file 
3) Do i need to modify the excel VBA code to fit Access?
2) Can Access handle a 300-500mb file?

thank you

Comment: There is no 'upgrade wizard' you can use. If you are comfortable with VBA then you should get started with Access but the _FIRST_ step is to come up with a data model, that is a bunch if tables that describe whatever it is you're trying to do. It might be that you need 2000 tables, one for each worksheet, but I doubt it. You should open up MS Access and have a look at some of the samples. What kind of business process is your Excel application modelling? i.e. supply chain, retail, medical, manufacturing, finance?

Answer (score 1):

500MB Excel file does not mean 500MB Access file. Moving from Excel to Access is a very good thought. However, you need to understand the basics first. Excel it completely different from MS Access access except when Access looks similar to excel in a datasheet form.

Access is a "Relational"-Database + graphical front-end software where you can present your data in a form or through components. In a relational database you identify entities and define relationships between them. By doing so you eliminate [Data inconsistency] throughout your application. A proper modelling might reduce your data from 500MB to just 50MB.

**To answer your questions:**

```
1> How to migrate the excel file to access?
```

First of all migration in your case needs a fresh new MS Application. Start modelling your business first. Read about Rational-Databases, Read about MS Access tables, relationships, queries. Think if Access is a suitable platform for your business. Create the application in MS Access and then you can come back to us and ask about migration.

**OR:**
You can use the current Excel sheet as an external data-source and link them as linked table within the access application. This is very very not recommended because you are effectively not benefiting anything better than your current situation. (Except queries to find a data)

```
2> Will the VBA program be carried to the new access file
```

Do you mean VBA forms? no it won't. Access has its own Forms and controls which looks better than Excel userforms. You have to redesign that part completely in Access.

```
3> Do i need to modify the excel VBA code to fit Access?
```

In most cases **YES** unless its a generic function. Most Excel VBA codes are referring to a cell or worksheet which Access does not have! In other words, it depends how big and complex your codes are. Any specific code has to be adjusted to MS Access platform but the adjustments are very minor not a major task. Again it depends on your code complexity.

```
4> Can Access handle a 300-500mb file?
```

Yes it can! newest versions can reach up to 2GB but i personally would not stay with access when i have to work with such amount of data. I would look for splitting/upgrading the database to a proper dedicated database engine such as MSSQL or free MySQL servers.

**Some advise from me:** 500MB of Excel sheet is potentially dangerous you should seek an alternative very soon. If you are going to fiddle on you own please always **"backup"** because Access throws random errors which are very hard to understand. Find an experienced IT person to help you before you delete/update/wipe off your data. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Interesting
I faced much of the same problem years ago on a POS system that recorded the transaction history in excel via some VBA. I moved to Access and found (Access) get a little corruptible the larger the file gets. I had to build in safeguards to restore from a backup should the file quit on me. I eventually moved to Visual FoxPro as my VBA could just about be translated straight across. Works to this day as a matter of fact.